# If you lose both Conflicts, does your Protagonist get two new Features?

Tags: conflicts, shock-social-science-fiction

When you lose a Conflict in *Shock:* your Protagonist increases hir Features number by one and you write a new Feature for zir. If you lose both Conflicts in the scene — i.e., the Antagonist wins hir Intent and you lose yours — does that mean you increase Features by two and write a new Feature reflecting each defeat?

Potentially going from 3 dice in the first scene to 5 dice in the second seems like a big deal, but it's not mentioned explicitly anywhere I can find, only by inference from the instructions for resolution, so I'm wondering if I'm missing something.

Comment: I approved an edit to this and then realised (by reading comments on the answer) that it was incorrect. Rolled it back.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I wonder if the unusual number of downvotes is because of the pronouns. Maybe they don’t know these are the pronouns used by the game.

Answer (score 4):

### The Antag winning does not mean the Protag loses.

Remember the rules of Intent (p.32): **the Intents of the players may not be mutually exclusive,** and for you dad-jokers in the audience, read that "may not" as "must not". It is always possible for the Protag and Antag to both win, or both lose, their Intents in a Conflict. Nothing that happens to the Antag counts for the Protag's win or loss.

However, it's possible to get up to **three** new Features from one failed Intent. Fail to accomplish your Intent in a Conflict. Risk a Link to redo the whole Conflict, and fail again. Risk the other Link to redo the whole Conflict **again** and fail **again**. This doesn't actually "redo" the Conflict; time still progresses to a greater or lesser degree, and the Praxis Scales can change, but you are risking more and more to accomplish your original Intent.

If your opposite *tagonist succeeds, you can still risk a Link, even if you succeeded too. But as long as you succeed in your Intent, you don't get a new Feature and you don't break a Link you risked.